# Left adjoint to Hom(_,M)

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, tensor-products, adjoint-functors

We know the tensor-hom adjuction where the functors are  $ \space \_ \otimes M $(*left adjoint*)  and $\operatorname{Hom}(M,\_)$(*right adjoint*). Now after this I wanted to find a left adjoint functor to the  (*left exact*) functor $\operatorname{Hom}(\_ , M)$,if any,but failed ! I would like to know whether it has a left adjoint and also if there is always a left adjoint(*right adjoint*) to a left exact(*right exact*) functor . Also when defining adjoint pair whether we always have to work in locally small categories(as we have to talk about bijections in the category of sets) ? It seems that WIKI does not say anything about locally small category when discussing adjoint pair ! I know only a bit of category theory .Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Related (for tensor product instead of Hom): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550458/when-does-tensor-product-have-a-exact-left-adjoint

Answer (score 3):

It is well known that a right adjoint preserves all limits that exist in its domain. You are looking for a converse.
Actually, under some conditions, the converse holds. This is known as **The Freyd Adjoint Functor Theorem** (see Mac Lane, *Categories for the working mathematician*, chapter V, section 6, Theorem 2).

Freyd Adjoint Functor Theorem. Given a small-complete category $A$ with small hom-sets, a functor $G:A\to X$ has a left adjoint *if and only if* it preserves all small limits and it satisfies the following *Solution Set Condition*. For each object $x\in X$ there exists a small set $I$ and an $I$-indexed family of arrows $f_i:x\to Ga_i$ such that every arrow $h:x\to Ga$ can be written as a composite $h=Gt\circ f_i$ for some index $i$ and some arrow $t:a_i\to a$.

Answer (score 2):

If your category is braided, i.e. you have a natural isomorphism $\tau_{AB} : A\otimes B \to B \otimes A$, then you have that $\text{Hom}(\_, M)^{op} \dashv \text{Hom}(\_, M) : \mathcal{C}^{op} \to \mathcal{C}$ assuming $\text{Hom}(\_,M)$ exists in the first place.  That is, $\text{Hom}(\_, M)$ is adjoint to itself on the right.  The unit-counit definition of an adjunction [immediately generalizes to an arbitrary 2-category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjunction#direct_definition).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to get this straight.

Comment: How can it be the case that $$\mathbf{Hom}(\_,M)$$ could not exist ?